# No consiguo cargar el chart en mi plantilla laravel

Tags: laravel, chart.js

Buenas estoy intententado realizar un chart.js de un grafico pero no consiguo cargar el grafico siempre me da error de "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined"  estoy siguendo un ejemplo de la documentacion tal cual pero no encuentro el problema dejo la linea de codigo que estoy usando.

```
 <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                    <script>
                        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
                        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'bar',
                            data: {
                                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: '# of Votes',
                                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                    ],
                                    borderColor: [
                                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                    ],
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                }]
                            },
                            options: {
                                scales: {
                                    yAxes: [{
                                        ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

Me esta devolviendo el fallo en esta linea.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
```

Comment: Tienes incluida la libreria? aqui si funciona https://jsfiddle.net/5f4trsL9/

Comment: si claro,     <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

Comment: Prueba a ponerla antes de comenzar el script, en el fiddle  funciona lo que tienes